# PHP SQL Query Not Returning values

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a php program that runs a query and outputs to an excel file. I have most of it working except for a few issues. I have the below query:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
        $DB_USER="";
        $DB_PASS="";
        $DB_TNS="";

        $contents="";
        $formattedDate=date('m_d_y',strtotime("-1 days"));
        $fileName="testDump";
        if($conn = oci_connect($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_TNS))
        {
                $sql = 'SELECT
                                drw.PROD_CODE delID
                        FROM
                                CIRC_RPT.VW_SUBS_DRW drw
                        JOIN CIRC.SUBSCRIPTION csub on csub.ACCOUNT = drw.account
                        where delivery_pub in (1,32) and drw.account = 47059092';
                $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
                oci_define_by_name($stid, 'delID', $delvID);
                oci_execute($stid);

                $handle = fopen("/usr/local/bin/next/FILES/".$fileName.".csv", "w");
                fwrite($handle, "First Name,Last Name,Email,Phone,HouseNumber,DeliveryScheduleId\n");

                while (OCIFetch($stid)){
                        $contents.=$delvID.",";
                        echo "delvID=".$delvID;
                        $contents="";
                }
                fclose($handle);
                oci_close($conn);
        }
        else
        {
                $e = oci_error();
                trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
?>
```

When I run the query in Squirrel SQL Client I for delvID I get back the value EE. However, in the above php I get nothing back in the echo. This is only happening for some of the values.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is this `SELECT drw.PROD_CODE delID` ? I think `SELECT  drw.PROD_CODE AS delID`

Comment: @NanaPartykar the AS doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried adding it just in case but I am still getting nothing back.

Comment: When selecting the fetched data, do a `print_r` and see what columns you are obtaining. It could be that the `JOIN` logic isn't executing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
    oci_define_by_name($stid, 'delID', &$delvID);
```

with an '&' before $delvID.

Hope it helps!
Cheers,
Viktor